# Preventing download of video

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I'm trying display a bunch of e-learning videos.  However, I don't want them to be downloaded.  Or, at worse, make it hard to download them.  Tried a few things like a website file protection rule but still have not been successful.  Any ideas out there?

Thanks
clem

Comment: „Making it hard“ is only possible with using an „encrypted“ stream provided by a streaming Server.

Comment: Or cut them up in small pieces and send each piece after each other. I've seen this way on some sites to handle chapters in the video as a bonus

Comment: The small pieces are still downloadable...